# How to give custom data to email template in odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I am unable to fetch custom data in email Template can anyone help me out regarding that here is my code.

```
class stu_rem(osv.osv):
_inherit = ['mail.thread']
_name = 'student.reminder'
_rec_name = 'stu_id'
_columns = {
        'stu_id' : fields.many2one("tender.hearts",'Student Name',required=True),
        'stu_name' : fields.char('Name Of the Student',invisible=True),
        'stu_father' : fields.char('Father Name',required=True),
        'stu_father_email' :  fields.char('Email ID',required=True),
        'stu_father_num':fields.char('Phone'),
        'next_pay_date_rem' : fields.date('Next Payment Date',required=True), 
        'r_date' : fields.date('Date'),
        'r_title' : fields.char('Subject for Email',required=True),
        'desc' : fields.text('Description'),
        'amt_pay' : fields.float('Pay Amount',required=True),
}
_defaults = {
        'r_date' : date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),

        'r_title' : 'Payment Reminder',
}

def action_payment_mail(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    '''
    This function opens a window to compose an email, with the edi sale template message loaded by default
    '''
    assert len(ids) == 1, 'This option should only be used for a single id at a time.'
    ir_model_data = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')
    stu_obj = self.browse(cr,uid,ids)
    feed_id = self.pool.get('student.reminder').browse(cr,uid,stu_obj[0])
    try:
        template_id = ir_model_data.get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'tenderhearts', 'email_template_edi_reminder_payment')[1]
    except ValueError:
        template_id = False
    try:
        compose_form_id = ir_model_data.get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'mail', 'email_compose_message_wizard_form')[1]
    except ValueError:
        compose_form_id = False 
    ctx = dict(context)
    # template_id = False
    # self.pool.get('sale.order').write(cr,uid,ids,{'state':'sent'},context=None)
    ctx.update({
        'default_model': 'student.reminder',
        'default_res_id': stu_obj[0].id,
        'default_use_template': bool(template_id),
        'default_template_id': template_id,
        'default_composition_mode': 'comment',
        'mark_so_as_sent': True
    })
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'mail.compose.message',
        'views': [(compose_form_id, 'form')],
        'view_id': compose_form_id,
        'target': 'new',
        'context': ctx,
    }
```

This is a friendly reminder to let u know that your payment for class 
activities is Part due. if you have already sent the payment, please discard this message.
Thank you for your continuous support.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

```
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_email_templates_reminder">
        <field name="name">Email Templates</field>
        <field name="res_model">email.template</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="email_template.email_template_tree" />
        <field name="search_view_id" ref="email_template.view_email_template_search"/>
        <field name="context">{'search_default_model_id':'student.reminder'}</field>
        <field name="context" eval="{'search_default_model_id': ref('Tenderheart.model_student_reminder')}"/>
    </record>

</data>

<data noupdate="0">
    <record id="email_template_edi_reminder_payment" model="email.template">
            <field name="name">${object.r_title}</field>
            <field name="email_from">no-reply@tenderhearts.ae</field>
            <field name="subject">${object.r_title}</field>
            <field name="context" eval="{'search_default_model_id': ref('Tenderheart.model_student_reminder')}"/>
            <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
            <field name="email_to">${object.stu_father_email}</field>
            <field name="body_html">
            <![CDATA[<div style="font-family: 'Lucica Grande', Ubuntu, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); background-color: #FFF; ">
            <h2 align="center"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/zUDvTMJ.jpg" width="100" height="52"/></h2>
            <h3>Dear Parents,</h3> 
            <h4>payment amount ${object.amt_pay}AED due on ${object.next_pay_date_rem} </h4>
            <h4>${object.desc}</h4>
           <h4>Best Regards.</h4>
           <h4>Tender Hearts Arena.</h4>
            </div>]]>
            </field>
    </record>
```

[Here is the snapshot of the data I want to fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4a82.png)

[Here is the snapshot of the mail which is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or37o.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this line replace :

```
 <field name="res_model">mail.template</field>
```

it may be works for you.

Comment: Thanks for replying jainik but I got it, it happens because I didn't mention the correct id   thanks all